# addColumn() in setup script TYPE_MEDIUMTEXT how? or text size?

Tags: magento-1.9, setup-script

in Mage setup sql scripts how do you add a column with text size medium? I'm not sure the 64kb limit of TYPE_TEXT will be long enough.

```
->addColumn('comments',Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,null,array(),'Comments')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074358/how-to-increase-maximum-size-of-csv-field-in-magento-where-is-this-located

Apparently you have to manually change the type of the field but it seems risky. One of the answers claims to have done it without any problems though.

Alternatively, you could try to estimate if your field will really need more space. MySQL type TEXT can fit a bit over 65, 000 characters.